# How to pull rows only from the weekends?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table data is like this:

```
ID   Name salary   date
1     a    100     1/08/2014
2     b    200     2/08/2014
.
.
.
.
26     z   2600    26/8/2014
```

Now I want to return only rows from Saturday or Sunday, like:

```
ID   Name salary   date
2    ------------------------
3     -----------------------
9
10
16
17
23
24
30
31 -------------------------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [DATENAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function and specify the *datepart* as `weekday`.

```
select ID, Name, Salary, Date
from dbo.yourTable
where datename(weekday, Date) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday');
```

As Aaron pointed out, this relies on the language being set to English.  Likewise, you could use the `DATEPART()` function with `weekday` and test for Saturday and Sunday values.

Comment: +1 Just make sure `SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;` :-) Alternatively, you could use `DATEPART` and check for the right integer, just make sure `SET DATEFIRST` is correct.

Comment: Great point, Aaron!!  I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone has been putting solutions that depend on setting either language or datefirst.
However, assuming that you're looking for dates only after 1900-01-01, (which was a Monday)

```
SELECT ID
       ,Name
       ,Salary
       ,Date
FROM <Table_Name>
WHERE DateDiff(dd, 0, Date) % 7 in (5,6)
```

Regardless of any settings, since 0 (or 1900-01-01) is a Monday, the modulo will always result in 5 or 6 for Sat and Sun respectively.

Comment: This answer translates well to other databases (e.g. MySQL) and is very performant as it is performing integer math. I usually do not like calculations to be performed in WHERE clauses (they must be performed for every row in the table) but if so, integer math is at least tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

One based on the name of the day of the week, the other based on the weekday number.

An example of using the name of the week day (in English, adapt to your local language)

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
  Salary,
  Date
FROM <table_name>
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday');
```

Alternatively, you can use `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date)`.

This uses the weekday number for a language independent method of getting the required output.

By Default, `Sunday = 1`, however you can customise this by setting the first day of the week using [`SET DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
  Salary,
  Date
FROM <table_name>
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) IN (1, 7);
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause using `GETDATE()` won't give the desired behavior.  That'll test for the current `datetime`, whether it is Saturday/Sunday.  You'd have to specify the `Date` column there to get the OP's end results.

Comment: Eugh..sorry..was testing my own logic...